# Does using bonjour on the iphone enable bluetooth automatically?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, wifi, bonjour

I am planning to a peer to peer app using bonjour for the iphone. There will be no wifi available and hence am relying on bluetooth. I know bonjour based services works over bluetooth in the abscense of wifi.

My question is, will bluetooth on the phone automatically become enabled when I launch the bonjour service or try to do discovery?

If not, how do I enable bluetooth - I can't find any public API's in the SDK?

Regards,
hb

Comment: btw - I am aware of the GameKit API.

Comment: I am wondering the possibility of directly using bonjour over bluetooth in iPhone OS 3.0 or later without using GameKit. Am I missing somthing for example a special parameter to pass to serachForServiceOfType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The user is responsible for selecting the network connectivity options in the Settings App. If they have not enabled Bluetooth, you cannot turn it on for them.

-t

Comment: also - this web link might also help others http://carpe-cocoa.com/2009-07-29/detecting-when-bluetooth-is-disabled-with-gksession/